# pass value to success function

Tags: javascript, jquery

is possible pass a value to `success` function?

```
function updateData(data_type){
  var current_url = "myUrl";
  var opc = data_type;
  var dataset = [];
  $.ajax({
    data : {'type': opc},
    url : current_url,
    type : 'get',
    success: function(data){
      update(data)
    }
  });
  console.log("update: " + data_type); 
}
```

Inside the `success` function I want to access my `data_type` variable that I pass by parameter.

It this possible?

Comment: Yes. You can just access `data_type` as it is. JavaScript has lexical scope. Maybe you can elaborate on what you tried and what problem you had with it.

Comment: `data_type` looks like it's already in scope.  Have you tried just using it in your success function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it directly, like this:

```
function updateData(data_type){
  var current_url = "myUrl";
  var opc = data_type;
  var dataset = [];
  $.ajax({
    data : {'type': opc},
    url : current_url,
    type : 'get',
    success: function(data){
       update(data, data_type);
    }
  });
  console.log("update: " + data_type); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tha'er Al-Ajlouni !! I don't know what happened before I check the function and I can use the value :(

Comment: You are welcome, kindly mark it as the correct answer for future references.

Answer (score 1):

```
function updateData( data_type ) {

  var current_url = "myUrl";
  var opc = data_type;
  var dataset = [];

  $.ajax( {
    data : {'type': opc},
    url : current_url,
    type : 'get',
    success: function( data ){
      // `data_type` is available here, use as needed.
      // You can pass it to other functions inside this one as well,
      // i.e. the function below could be `update( data, data_type );`.
      update( data );
    }
  } );

  console.log( "update: " + data_type ); 

}
```

Comment: Thanks @hungerstar !! I don't know what happened before I check the function and I can use the value :(